# MYSQL STORED PROCEDURE with OUTFILE with no spaces in txt file

Tags: mysql, sql, into-outfile

I would like to export a query result in a txt file, but with no field separators

like this:
field1field2field3field4

if I use the fields terminated by and optionally enclosed by and set them to '', I still get some kind of tabs between fields...

How can I get the output right?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Could you try something like...

```
SELECT field1 || field2 || field3 AS answer
    FROM mytable;
```

Or if your query is not something you want to fiddle with too much,

```
SELECT field1 || field2 || field3 AS answer
    FROM (other query in here) AS mytable;
```